# operation size not specified

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I have a problem with 32bit Assembly, assembling it with NASM on linux.
Here is my implementation of insertion sort

```
myInsertionSort:
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
push ebx
push esi
push edi
mov ecx, [ebp+12]   ;put len in ecx, our loop variable
mov eax, 1 ; size of one spot in array, one byte
mov ebx, 0
mov esi, [ebp+8] ; the array
loop loop_1
loop_1:
    cmp eax, ecx ; if we're done
    jge done_1 ; then done with loop
    push ecx ; we save len, because loop command decrements ecx
    mov ecx, [esi+eax] ; ecx now array[i]
    mov ebx, eax
    dec ebx ; ebx is now eax-1, number of times we should go through inner loop
    loop_2:
        cmp ebx, 0 ; we don't use loop to not affect ecx so we use ebx and compare it manually with 0
        jl done_2
        cmp [esi+ebx], ecx ;we see if array[ebx] os ecx so we can exit the loop
        jle done_2
        mov edx, esi
        add edx, ebx
        push [edx] ; pushing our array[ebx] *****************************
        add edx, eax
        pop [edx] ; poping the last one *********************************
        dec ebx ; decrementing the loop iterator
        jmp loop_2 ; looping again
    done_2:
        mov [esi+ebx+1], ecx
        inc eax ; incrementing iterator
        pop ecx ; len of array to compare now to eax and see if we're done
        jmp loop_1
done_1:
    pop edi
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    pop ebp ; we pop them in opposite to how we pushed (opposite order, it's the stack, LIFO)
    ret
```

Now... When I try to compile my code with nasm, I get errors of "operation size not specified" on the lines containing asterisks in the comments :P
It's basic insertion sort and I'm not sure what could have gone wrong.
Enlighten me, please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data at `[edx]` could be anything, so its size is unknown to the assembler. You'll have to specify the size of the data you want to push/pop. For example, if you want to push/pop a `dword` (32 bits) you'd write:

```
push dword [edx]
pop dword [edx]
```

---

By the way, you can combine these lines:

```
mov edx, esi
add edx, ebx
```

into:

```
lea edx,[esi + ebx]
```

Comment: Indeed, thank you. Another thing, if i may:http://pastebin.com/dZ4UmJ0Q
Can you see a problem here ? It prints TONS of garbage value and random numbers and announces a segmentation fault when in printArray

Comment: You're only pushing one item before calling `printf`!

Comment: @FRankKotler Yes. Now I've fixed that but a segmentation fault pops when in loop_2 in insertion sort, could you please help me to find the problem ? http://pastebin.com/dbRh58f2

Comment: If you have further questions you should post them as separate questions rather than using the comment field for that. Remember to include the relevant code and information directly in your question(s), rather than linking to it.